# where to find example of logIN and logOUt operations in web service?

Tags: service, jax-ws

I looking for a web services tutorial using Jax-ws wherein it has login/logout methods. for the login it will return the session id. for the logout it will end the session.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
winston

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links:

[wsaddressing](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/jax-ws-21-ea3/docs/wsaddressing.html)

[ws_addressing_and_stateful_webservice](http://blogs.oracle.com/sujit/entry/ws_addressing_and_stateful_webservice)

[stateful-web-services-axis2](https://www.wso2.org/library/articles/stateful-web-services-axis2)

[Stateful Web Service with JAX-WS RI](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/nonav/2.1/docs/statefulWebservice.html)